# How to send emails using Google App Engine Mail Service?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to be able to send emails out from my GAE app.
My personal email is registered with the permission "Is Owner"
I am using this as the from email following the example on this page.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/
I tried sending the email with my application deployed to GAE.

I get an error message and getting the following exception
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission.

I am just trying send a dummy email to test it out.

Also if I eventually get this working and I want to use some generic purpose email like admin@mydomain.com, how do I achieve this?

Comment: apps of GAE can ONLY send mail via your google account (id used to create app) . i used GAE as a student in a while ill put the code . there is hardly any changes to be done for JavaMail to work with gmail GAE

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the recipient's email. You are trying to send to a blocked address (probably something generic like test@example.com). Try changing the recipient's address to something else

As to your second question, you can only send email from admin emails or addresses ending in: @appid.appspotmail.com

So if you want to send from admin@mydomain.com you should add it to your admins of the apps (of course, the email must be a google account)